How to generate new private and public key pairs in dotenvx?

I am using dotenvx in my project.
I also used dotenvx encrypt (documentation link) and am happy.

Got a public and private secp256k1 key pair.



Problem: I now want to generate a new key pair (for whatever security related reason) but can't find any information on how to do this from the docs/online.

I have tried the following to no avail.

Ran dotenvx decrypt then did another dotenvx encrypt.
Ran dotenvx decrypt, renamed .env.keys which has the private key, did another dotenvx encrypt.

Same above but deleted .env.keys.






This does not appear to be a programming question.

Found the answer while in the middle of submitting the question.

Ensure to run dotenvx decrypt to not lose secrets
Remove the keys (back them up just to be safe)

DOTENV_PUBLIC_KEY from .env
DOTENV_PRIVATE_KEY from .env.keys


Run dotenvx encrypt - Solves the problem, now there is a new public and private key pair
Cleanup .env & .env.keys from extra generated comments due to new key pair


yes, that's the current solution. i hadn't thought about this. maybe I should add a dotenvx rotate command?

How about dotenvx keypair -f renew .env.myenv?

possibly. tracking here: https://github.com/dotenvx/dotenvx/issues/478
